# How to have the menu mnemonic underline appearing always?

Tags: javafx, mnemonics

When a mnemonic character `"_"` is added to the menu text, we have to press the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key to make the mnemonic underline appear. How to let the menu mnemonic underline appear always before we press <kbd>Alt</kbd>?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To make the mnemonic underlines visible all the time, just add the following to your css file:

```
.mnemonic-underline {
    -fx-stroke: -fx-text-base-color;
}
```

Comment: You actually want `-fx-stroke: -fx-text-fill`, so it can change color when the menu item is selected